# What exactly is going on here? (Python 3.7.6)

Tags: python, iterator, iterable, keyword-argument, variable-length

I'm studying someone else's solution on Codewars and am a little puzzled about something. Here is a link to the original question: [Reverse or Rotate?](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56b5afb4ed1f6d5fb0000991/solutions/python). Credit goes to the original author, **falsetru**.

Here's the solution:

```
def revrot(strng, sz):
    return ''.join(
        chunk[1:] + chunk[:1] if sum(int(d)**3 for d in chunk) % 2 else chunk[::-1]
        for chunk in map(''.join, zip(*[iter(strng)]*sz))
    )
```

I think I understand most of it. Except for this part:

```
zip(*[iter(strng)]*sz)
```

I think that the * used in this way signifies a non-keyworded variable-length argument list - meaning that there could be any number of pieces of the original string (`strng`), which are of length `sz`, for example, 6. The `zip()` function is receiving some variable number of iterables, which is what it requires, per the documentation. (Right?)

So then, `map(''.join, zip(*[iter(strng)]*sz)` first returns an iterator for the string `strng`. It returns this inside of a list. It seems like that list is then multiplied by `sz` (why?). It returns a variable number of results to zip (thus the `*`). `zip()` returns a tuple (I guess?), which is then passed through the `join` function via `map`.

Questions:

1. Is that even close to being right?
2. Why must iter(strng) be placed inside a list `[]`?
3. Why can you join the result of `zip`? I tried joining `('m',)` as a test and got `'m'`. Confused as to why that works as well.
4. Can someone explain more about the *? I'm confused as to when I should use it...

Thanks. I'm still a late beginner in Python so I appreciate the help! (Even for just a piece of my question!)

Comment: It's one of the techniques used for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks . But in general, "please explain this code to me" is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, because it's hard to understand what is preventing you from figuring it out yourself, and because there are multiple aspects to the confusion (i.e., "needs more focus").

Comment: Hi Karl, so sorry. I'll definitely be more focused and specific next time. Should I have split this post into smaller questions and posted them separately? Also, thank you for that link; I'll have a thorough look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what is happening, we want to analyze the statement

```
for chunk in map(''.join, zip(*[iter(strng)]*sz))
```

Inside out:

1. `iter(strng)` returns an iterator that each time is accessed using `next` or in an  loop ***consumes*** an element (a character) of `strng` and returns said element.
2. `[iter(strng)]` is a list, its unique element is the iterator
3. `[iter(strng)]*sz` is the concatenation of `sz` copies of the list, `[iter(strng), ..., iter(strng)]` containing `sz` times ***the same iterator object***, I mean ***literally the same iterator object***.
4. `*[iter(strng)]*sz` is equivalent to `*[iter(strng), ..., iter(strng)]` and, when used in a function argument list, *unpacks* its contents: the function sees its list of arguments as `(iter(strng), ..., iter(strng))`.
5. `zip(*[iter(strng)]*sz)` is hence equivalent to `zip(iter(strng), ..., iter(strng))`.
6. At each iteration `zip` takes the first element of each of its arguments and place them in a tuple, but because the various references to `iter` all refer to the same, original instance of `iter(strng)` the first tuple returned by `zip` contains the first `sz` characters of `strng`, the second contains the `sz+1` to `2*sz` characters etc etc.
7. Finally, each of this tuples is the argument of `''.join()`, so we have a series of strings each long `sz` characters, spanning the original `strng`.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was very clear. I appreciate it.